# What is the use of private constructor in java?

Tags: java, static, constructor, abstract-class

private constructor do not allow to create objects for example here is code..

```
class emp
{
    private emp()//private constructor
    {

    }
}

public class privateconstructor
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        emp e = new emp();//throws Error as constructor not visible

    }

}
```

By declaring the class as **abstract** user can also be prevented to create object ..so my question is why private constructor?
Just for Info:
Though object can be created by **static** method for example..

```
class emp
{
    private emp()//private constructor
    {

    }
    static emp createInstance()//static method
    {
        return new emp();//returns an instance
    }

    void disp()
    {
        System.out.println("member function called");
    }
}

public class privateconstructor
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        emp e = emp.createInstance();//creating object by static method  
        e.disp();

    }

}
```

output: member function called

Comment: it ensures you no one will able to create a new instance(Unless that one knows Reflection), useful when you want one instance of a class, like Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 5):

> so my question is why private constructer?

This is done to prevent construction of a class from any other class.  This is usually used in utility classes, singletons, or classes which have factory methods instead of constructors.

All `enum` classes have private constructors and they can also be useful for Utility and Singleton classes.

Comment: if you dont now anything about singleton see following link:  http://www.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-singleton

Answer (score 0):

There are some Objects that depend on specific things. Suppose Runtime class , its instance will be dependent on System's current Runtime environment. So instead of,

```
Runtime run = new Runtime();  //java.lang.Runtime
```

RunTime's Object is created by:

```
Runtime ru = Runtime.getRuntime();
```

So classes that do not let Objects to be created just like that use private constructor.